# Why is this question considered 'close-worthy'

Tags: discussion, support, closing

Quite some time ago I asked a question and it was closed if memory serves.

The question is, "[What are all the ways to generate EU in Feed The Beast?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131369/what-are-my-eu-options-in-unhinged)" (10k only as it is deleted)

[image]

Such an answer would be a small list of all the blocks that act as EU generators. Why would this question be a bad one?

Comment: Does the question still exist (even if closed)? A link to it for the full content and thus likely proper context would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say this is entirely unanswerable without that context, unless your claim that the answer is a small bounded list is untrue (in which case the answer should be obvious).

Comment: I can no longer find it, ill just re-ask it and followup

Comment: I'm guessing [this one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131369/what-are-my-eu-options-in-unhinged) (10k only).

Comment: @Ender misread the first sentence, nevermind.

Comment: @oak you found it!!

Comment: having know knowledge for that mod, seems like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: blah, meant no knowledge :P